# Why is java telling me that my package does not exist?

Tags: java, import, javafx, importerror

I have two files. One is a Java file named BattleShip. The other is a JavaFX file named BattleShipJavaFX. I want to import a class from BattleShipJavaFX to BattleShip. I keep receiving this error:

[image: Error Image]

For clarification, here is an image of the package name of my BattleShipJavaFX file

[image: BattleShipJavaFX]

I have been trying to get this package to import for the past 2 hours and I'm becoming increasingly frustrated. A lot of the links I have looked to for help say they must be in the same directory. If I'm interpreting that correctly, then mine are indeed in the same directory as you can see below:

[image: directory]

Do they mean that these files need to be located where all other packages are located (ie; Do my files need to be moved to the location where java package is stored?)? If so, where would that be located?

If not, PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE tell me what my problem is. This is my first time using JavaFX and I've only been using Java in general for 3 weeks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't the packages be in the `src` directory?

Comment: Do both folders belong to you source path?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I copied the JAVA file from the src folder in my battleshipjavafx folder and put it in the src folder in my battleship folder. This allowed the import to be successful to a point. It successfully imported something, but when I tried to run a test class from the imported package, it said the code was uncompilable. I'm assuming that particular java file only contained a stub basically saying "this exists and can be called!", but didnt have the actual code to be implemented. Anyways, thanks for the help >.< back to the grind...

Comment: There is a "Projects" window panel (Ctrl+1) in Netbeans. Unfold all packages of your project and post its screenshot.

Comment: I gather that your classes are living in separate projects...so...have you configured your BattleShip project to reference your BattleShipJavaFX project?

Comment: @kem I found a fix for my problem, but if you could remind me how to reference another project, that would be really helpful. I'm sure I learned how to do that and have just forgotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. Posting answer in case any other Java newbies run into this problem.

The problem was that I made two separate projects and then tried to import one project into another, when what I really needed to do was have the two files inside the same package.

As you can see from the picture below, I moved copied BattleShipJavaFX.Java and just pasted it into my battleship class. My program now works as intended.

[image: Solution]

Thanks to everyone who helped me out.